# VBA code to select last row amd next empty row

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA code that selects the last non-empty row and the next empty row and do a data series to autofill the date but not getting a headway, please assist. code is below:

```
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=9
Range("A8560:A8561").Select
Selection.DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlChronological, Date:= _
    xlDay, Step:=1, Trend:=False
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: consider about [accepting answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) on previous questions before asking for new ones.

Answer (score 1):

To select the last non-empty row in column A use:

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Activate
```